# How to return ICollection from method?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Consider following method

```
public ICollection<int> method()
{
    ICollection<int> col = new List<int>();
    return col;
}

HashSet<int> result = (HashSet<int>) method();
```

Of course I'm getting error "Unable to cast object of type List to HashSet", because I've instantiaded col with List in method()

Is it possible to have generic method, which return ICollection and can be casted at HashSet or List, depending on my needs?

Comment: No.  The object you return is either a List or a HashSet, not both.  If you need one or the other, your method should return one or the other.  Casting the result of a method call breaks encapsulation and is not good practice.

Comment: That was mine assumption, then why is it advised to return ICollection, if I need to instantiate it with concrete collection? Why not just make return type of List<int> or HashSet<int>?

Comment: If the caller of the method is only supposed to use the methods available from ICollection, then yes, it is preferable to return an ICollection.

Comment: By returning the interface, the author of the method is communicating "you must not rely on me returning any particular kind of collection; I might change what kind of collection is returned in the future*.  Pay attention to what the author of the method is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't straight cast it because the instance returned is not a `HashSet` or anything but a `List`, but you can easily use the `ICollection` instance returned to initialize a new instance of whatever you need.  For example:

```
ICollection<int> result = Method();
HashSet<int> newHashSet = new HashSet<int>(result);
```